# Methods supported in windows mobile

Tags: c#, windows-mobile, outlook, smtp

is CreateMHTMLBody supported in windows mobile?..
How to send the entire webapage as attachment to server in windows mobile either using c# or C++

Answer (score 0):

You mean the [IMessage.CreateHTMLBody](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa487621(EXCHG.65).aspx) in CDO?  If so, then no, CDO doesn't even exist in Windows CE or WinMo.  Though that's for creating an HTML body message (i.e. email) and you're talking about a web page.  If you want to send an HTML file with an email, then just [add](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsmobile.pocketoutlook.attachmentcollection.add.aspx) the file as an [attachment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsmobile.pocketoutlook.attachment_members.aspx) to your message via POOM.

Comment: Catcke, My idea was to Save Webpage locally in .mht formate(Archive Webpage) and send to server.. is it possible in win mob.. please let me.. i am waiting for your reply..
Thanks